# Div float positioning

Tags: html, css

I feel like this is a very simple problem but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. What I have is a bunch of `divs` added to a container. Then I want those divs to freely position them self in any white space, but they must move from *top to bottom*, *left to right*. I also can not adjust the order of the divs. Here is an example of my problem http://jsfiddle.net/8GMGF/1/. I need the blue box to automatically move into the free space above it. Thanks for any input.

PS. I also tried flexboxes but they don't seem to be able to use free space either. Maybe I missed something.

Comment: Ah, yes. Thanks but I forgot to mention that the orange container will dynamically change with the size of the window, and I would rather not have this huge space in the middle. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Pure CSS is probably not going to work.  See http://stackexchange.com/sites for a JavaScript example that looks like what you are trying to do.

Comment: That's disappointing. I was hoping to stay out of a Javascript solution for this.

Comment: Unfortunately with the level of control you want you might need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result you are looking for (with the subtle tweaks you want to make) might not be possible with pure html and css, you may wish to look into using a tiling plugin such as Masonary for jQuery:

http://masonry.desandro.com/index.html

Comment: An example of a similar solution called [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co) is used on the [StackExchange site list](http://stackexchange.com/sites).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't really even know what I was looking for.